# Tar: create archive exclude directories except one

Tags: unix, gzip, archive, tar

I have some directories with some files

```
dir_archive/somedir1
dir_archive/somedir2
dir_archive/somedir3
dir_archive/mydir
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir1
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir2
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir3
dir_archive/mydir/many_other_directories...
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir
```

I want create tar(gz) archive dir_archive.tar.gz with all files and directories exclude

```
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir1
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir2
dir_archive/mydir/excludedir3
dir_archive/mydir/many_other_directories...
```

but include

```
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir
```

I dont want use `--exclude` for each directory

```
tar cvfz dir_archive.tar.gz --exclude=dir_archive/mydir/excludedir1 --exclude=dir_archive/mydir/excludedir2 --exclude=dir_archive/mydir/excludedir3
```

I try use `--add-file`, but it doesn't work:

```
tar cvfz dir_archive.tar.gz --exclude=dir_archive/mydir --add-file=dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir dir_archive
```

Exists some simple way? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way would be first excluding the `mydir` and then appending the `my_archive_dir`

```
tar cvf dir_archive.tar --exclude=dir_archive/mydir dir_archive
tar rvf dir_archive.tar dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir
gzip dir_archive.tar
```

Unfortunately appending doesn't work with zipped archives.

The `--exclude` option takes a pattern as argument, so if the names of the dirs to be excluded are similar, you can avoid them and still include the archive dir

```
tar cvfz dir_archive.tar.gz --exclude=dir_archive/mydir/exclude* dir_archive
```

It is also possible to create a file with names of all the files that you want included and give that list to tar with option `-T` or `--files-from` (or in similar fashion list the files to be excluded and give the list with option `-X`).

```
filelist.txt:
dir_archive
dir_archive/temp1
dir_archive/mydir
dir_archive/mydir/temp2
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir/temp7
```

```
tar cvfz dir_archive.tar.gz --no-recursion --files-from filelist.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for exhaustive answers

Comment: Beware, tar implicitly puts a `*` before each line in the -X input; dir_archive will match dir_archive/dir_archive, which *could* be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters:

```
$ mkdir -p dir_archive/{somedir{1..3},mydir/{excludedir{1..3},otherone,my_archive_dir}}
$ touch dir_archive/{somedir{1..3},mydir/{excludedir{1..3},otherone,my_archive_dir}}/dir_file.txt
$ tar cvzf dir_archive.tar.gz dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir* --exclude "dir_archive/mydir/*" dir_archive
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir/
dir_archive/mydir/my_archive_dir/dir_file.txt
dir_archive/
dir_archive/mydir/
dir_archive/somedir2/
dir_archive/somedir2/dir_file.txt
dir_archive/somedir1/
dir_archive/somedir1/dir_file.txt
dir_archive/somedir3/
dir_archive/somedir3/dir_file.txt
```

What this is doing in essence is being more explicit up front, then applying the exclude to the parent directory only.

Stolen shamelessly from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417707/420501