# Tar a directory excluding a some particular directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a tricky task to perform in Linux using tar. Can you help me out?

Below is my directory structure. Directory named Harry contains, below mentioned text files and directories.

```
Harry/
   -> file1.txt
   -> file2.txt
   -> file3.txt
   -> chocobar/
   -> restobar/
   -> bluebar/
   -> direct1/
```

My main task here is to write a script which tar all the files and directories of Harry into a package named "smallHarry.tar.gz". However, one of the argument to the script contains any of the above mentioned 'bar' directory. Excluding all the other 'bar' directories tar should be created.

For example: If I give "`./myscript restobar`", `tar` should include all files and then only '`restobar/`' and 'direct1/' directories. All other directories with 'bar' string ('`chocobar`' and '`bluebar`') must be excluded.

I know that I can do "`tar -zcvf Harry/ * -exclude 'chocobar' -exclude 'bluebar'`". But I want a generic script. Because directories with string 'bar' will increase in future and I don't want to update the script every time I get a new directory with string 'bar'.

Comment: See: [Tar: create archive exclude directories except one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10227892/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

What about ignoring all folders and adding the one you want manually? Something along these lines:

Script:

```
find Harry/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs tar -zcvf ${2} Harry/${1}
```

Running `./script.sh restobar test`:

```
Harry/restobar/
Harry/restobar/2/
Harry/file2.txt
Harry/file1.txt
```

Structure `Harry/`:

```
Harry/
├── bluebar
├── chocobar
│   └── 1
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── restobar
    └── 2
```

Generated tar:

```
drwxrwxr-x reut/reut         0 2016-05-23 21:56 Harry/restobar/
drwxrwxr-x reut/reut         0 2016-05-23 21:56 Harry/restobar/2/
-rw-rw-r-- reut/reut         0 2016-05-23 21:48 Harry/file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- reut/reut         0 2016-05-23 21:48 Harry/file1.txt
```

Comment: This looks good. What, if the directory "Harry/"contains more directories like "direct1/", "direct2/" (no bar string for them) and I want these directories should also be included in the tar?